# How to make React page render only change component instead of the whole page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I have a toggle looking like this (see below), but the page always re-render **the whole thing** on the **first time** I click on the toggle.

```
export default function Toggle({isChecked, label}: Props) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Switch isChecked={isChecked}>
        <span />
      </Switch>
      {label}
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Then another component which is using this Toggle component

```
export default function ToggleBox({isChecked, label, children}: Props) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Toggle isChecked={isChecked} label={label} />
      <Content>{children}</Content>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

There is a layout

```
export default function Layout({...someprops bla bla, children}: Props) {
  <Wrapper>
       <DesktopImg>
        <ImageWrapper>
          <Image src={image.url} alt={`${headline} image`} layout="fill" />
       </ImageWrapper>
    </DesktopImg>
    <div>
      <Content>
        {back && backButton}
         <MobileImg>
           <Image
            src={image.url}
            alt={`${headline} image`}
            width={image.width}
            height={image.height}
           />
          </MobileImg>
          {headline}
          <P gutterSize="medium">{description}</P>
          </Content>
          <ChildrenContainer>{children}</ChildrenContainer>
         </div>
        </Wrapper>
}
```

Then finally the page which use the ToggleBox.

```
export default function Index({isChecked, label, children}: Props) {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false)
    return (
     <Layout>
        <div onClick={() => setCheck(!check)}>
          <ToggleBox label="some label..." isChecked={check}>
            //sometext..
          </ToggleBox>
        </div>
        <Button onClick={nextPage} disabled={!check}>
          Next
        </Button>
     </Layout>
    )
 }
```

I kinda tried to use the `React.memo` method but it doesnt seem to work. Any suggestion to make the page not re-render the whole thing but just the toggle?

Comment: The page holds the `check` state, why wouldn't it re-render? If you want only `Toggle` to rerender, it has to be without state dependencies.

Comment: what are you expecting _not_ to rerender, becuase the fact that `ToggleBox` accepts the changing prop, the only thing that wouldn't rerender if you used `memo` would be the button, which to me is nothing to worry about.  You can _over_ memoize too don't forget...

Comment: @DennisVash Can you write a better architecture suggestion? Because I'm not understanding what you mean

Comment: @andymccullough I'm expecting the whole page not to re-render but only the button and the toggle itself. I used memo everywhere, in the Toggle, ToggleBox and Index. Doesn't work

Comment: Please make a simple codesandbox, its not clear what are the dependencies here [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), why clicking Toggle changing state? There isn't any setter function in this component.

Comment: @DennisVash How is it not clear here? I'm using styled-components on this. `Index` has the `check` state which pass into the `ToggleBox` which pass into `Toggle`... Not understand what is not clear here

Comment: Your `Index` component holds the `check` state, therefore on changing it (in your example you do it by the `onClick` event on the `div` element), every component which depends on this state will re-render. Again, why you expect the page to NOT re-render when you changing its state?

Comment: @DennisVash Sorry, I edited the code now. As you can see in the new version. The whole page re-render. I only want the `ToggleBox` and the `Button` part to re-render

Comment: Ok, so put all other content that does not depend on check state into React.memo and it will work.

Comment: @DennisVash I tried, doesnt work. I updated my code again, I added the memo to `Layout` but doesnt work

Comment: Again, make a codesdanbox, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your state further down the tree, you want it to be as close to the component(s) it impacts as possible, again this will probably require breaking out into smaller components, for example, break out the following into a seperate component -

```
const NewToggleComponent = () => {
   const [check, setCheck] = useState(false)
   return (
       <div onClick={() => setCheck(!check)}>
          <ToggleBox label="some label..." isChecked={check}>
            //sometext..
          </ToggleBox>
        </div>
        <Button onClick={nextPage} disabled={!check}>
          Next
        </Button>
   )
}
```

remove state from the top level component, and use this component in your top level component -

```
...
<NewToggleComponent />
...
```

Comment: if what you have tried is the new edit on your page, you still have your state at the highest component, you need to _move_ your state to a lower component in the tree, the example component I have above *does not* contain what you now have as `Layout`, the example component I have above is a small component that is used within what is now Layout, and the state is held only within the small component above (NewToggleComponent).  The higher you have state in your component tree, the more components _under_ it will render

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. So where would I move it ? Sorry for my annoying question. I just really want to make this bug go away :(